# Initialize vector with different values

Tags: c++

I have the following structure:

```
enum model_class
{
    ...
};

struct SModelData
{
    string       m_strName;
    model_class  m_class;
    vector<int>  m_parts;
    int          m_iSeats;

    SModelData(...) : ... {}
};

const multimap<int, SModelData*> models_data =
{
    { 400, new SModelData("Landstalker", STUFF, ***, 4) },
    ...
};
```

m_parts can have different int values (const) and their count.
E.g. model 401 will have: 6661, 6662, 6669, 6674 ;
model 402: 6669, 6670 ;
etc.

Which is the best way to get that stuff?

Comment: First of all I don't recommend you have pointers to the structure in you map. Secondly, do you really need a `std::multimap`? Can a single key have multiple values? Thirdly you initialize a vector very similar to how you initialize the map, using a brace-enclosed list to create a [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list). If you don't need a pointer then you don't need a constructor either by the way.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I changed type to basic map, thanks. It works well with initializer_list (perhaps), thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Having *raw* owning pointers stored in STL containers is generally a bad idea, and source of bugs:

> ```
> const multimap<int, SModelData*> models_data =
> ```

I would prefer using either *smart* owning pointers (e.g. `shared_ptr<SModelData>` for shared ownership semantic, or `unique_ptr<SModelData>` for unique ownership semantic), or just use `SModelData` *values*.

Moreover, are you sure you want to use a `multimap`?

Maybe a `map` with values would be just fine?

e.g.:

```
const map<int, SModelData> models_data
```

To initialize your `const map`, you may just use C++11 initializer lists, or a lambda, e.g.:

```
const auto models_data = []() -> map<int, SModelData> {
    map<int, SModelData> data;

    // ... Fill your map

    return data;
}();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yep, I already moved to map instead of multimap and SModelData instead of SModelData*.